# What religion did Mustafa Kemal Atatürk self-identify as following?

Tags: religion, ottoman-empire, turkey

He was born in the Ottoman Empire (later Turkey), so I assume he was a Muslim. But when I checked his attitude towards religion, it became clear that he saw religion as an obstacle in making progression. This made him abolish the Sharia law, the caliphate, the Arabic alphabet/calendar, etc. This seems strange to me, if he was a Muslim.

So was [Mustafa Kemal Atatürk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustafa_Kemal_Atat%C3%BCrk) an atheist, a Muslim or something else?

Comment: What did your [preliminary research show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustafa_Kemal_Atat%C3%BCrk%27s_personal_life)?  This question may be closed as trivial since the answer is in Wikipedia.  Ataturk was a secularist.

Comment: Well, since Wikipedia isn't the most reliable source, I thought maybe someone here knows a reliable source of Atatürk's religion.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Well, secularism does not necessarily imply atheism, but neither does it preclude being a Muslim. Does Wikipedia actually say whether he was a Muslim or an atheist? If not, then I think this question is valid, although it does spent a paragraph confusing secularism with not being a Muslim.

Comment: [help] asserts that H:SE questions should not be answerable by Wikipedia or Google.  We generally reject any question as trivial if the answer can be found through simple research.  If you want to save your question from being closed, please show the preliminary research you've done and why you have rejected it.

Comment: @Semaphore - excellent point - Wikipedia quotes a Muslim scholar as saying that Ataturk was not Muslim because *the scholar*  does not approve of Ataturk's behavior.  How should we answer the question if Ataturk claimed to be Muslim, but contemporaries denied this?  Kind of like Jefferson was accused of atheism, but claimed to be Christian.  If you do cursory preliminary research, the question becomes non-trivial.   I've checked my list of credentials, and discovered that nobody has granted me the power to determine whether anyone is a Muslim </wry>

Comment: By comparison: none of the US leaders claimed that he was an atheist. Most of them were Christians, by default. Most of them attended church. Nevertheless they separated religion from the state, and always firmly kept this separation from the very beginning. Why are you so surprised that a  Muslim leader did the same?

Comment: @Alex: Perhaps the reason is that historically, in Islam religion and the state were the same thing, so by separating religion from the state, he becomes an apostate.  Whereas Christianity more or less explicitly separates religion from the state - the bit about "Render unto Caesar..."

Comment: @jamesqf Historically christianism and state were the same thing too. It took centuries of confrontations among civil and religious leaders until the idea of separating religion from state took hold. And even today that's a fight that must be kept fighting to prevent unpleasent comebacks.

Comment: @jamesqf: The key word here is "historically". Whatever J. Christ and Mohammed said, the idea of separation of religion from the state, is a relatively modern idea (as also the idea of the modern state itself).

Comment: @Rekesoft That depened upon the state, and the century you are referring to.  Your overgeneralization is not useful, and is not accurate.  ON the other hand, when the Emperor of Rome made Christianity his religion (and later among the Eastern / Greek churches) an amount of formal fusion of those roles carried forward for centuries. (Likewise with Russian Tsars).

Comment: This question would be improved if you identify what period of Mustafa Kemal's you are referring to.  No few people have changed their religious beliefs/preferences over the course of their life time.  (IIRC, Buddha began his life among the Vedic Brhamins ... and then saw the light ... but that's another topic).

Comment: @Rekesoft: Look at the scriptures of the religions, and at their full history.  Islam always was the state, starting from when Mohammed took over Medina.  Christianity had several centuries (until Constantine) when it was an outlaw religion.  There was a middle period in which Christianity endorsed/legitimized the state (and vice versa), but AFAIK there are few instances where it actually WAS the state.  Which made later separation much easier.

Comment: @jamesqf As a general rule, whatever the founder of a religion said, or even whatever it is written in their sacred books, and what the rulers of said religion do afterwards have nothing in common. Saying that christianity made separation of church and state easier because "render unto Caesar" it's like saying that christianism favored communism because "it is easier for a camel to go through the eye of a needle than for someone who is rich to enter the kingdom of God".

Answer (score 2):

[Grace Ellison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Ellison) was a British journalist who interviewed [Mustafa Kemal Atatürk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustafa_Kemal_Atat%C3%BCrk) in person.  She described one interview in her 1928 book [Turkey To-day](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.81751/page/n27).  This interview would be quoted by Andrew Mango in his 2011 biography titled '[Atatürk](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cO50m62MA8AC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)' to illustrate Atatürk's secular and rationalist credentials.

Of particular relevance here are her questions about the modernising reforms that he was proposing and his responses to those questions (pp23-24).

---

Atatürk said:

> "... In two years’ time every woman must have her face uncovered and work side by side with men; and the men will wear hats. The day when clothes were the symbol of a religion has passed. The fez which symbolized a faith despised by Western civilization must go, and all the fanaticism that goes with it!"

Ellison raised the question of how the *hodjas* [Muslim schoolmasters] might react to his reforms.  Atatürk replied:

> "The hodjas! Indeed you are right! We have been a priest-ridden nation too long. Our reverend friends must learn to behave themselves. If they refuse, — well, they can always join the Sultan."

Ellison went on to quote Atatürk as saying:

> "You speak of religion," said he, when I had expressed my doubts as best I could. "**I have no religion; and at times I wish all religions at the bottom of the sea**."

- (my emphasis)

This would certainly suggest that he self-identified as an atheist or, at the very least as an agnostic.

---

However, notwithstanding that last remark, it is clear that Atatürk had no wish to impose his own views on others.  Ellison continued:

> "He is a weak ruler," said the Ghazi, "who needs religion to uphold his government; it is as if he would catch the people in a trap. My people are going to learn the principles of democracy, the dictates of truth, and the teachings of science. Superstition must go. Let them worship as they will ; **every man can follow his own conscience; provided it does not interfere with sane reason**, or bid him act against the liberty of his fellow-men."

- (my emphasis)